# What are *.php.1 - *.php.2 files?

Tags: php, file, cron

can't find anything on Google about this.

So, I have been playing with crons yesterday. I have created a cron file which would be active and is called `notidy.php`.

Today, I found a copy of that file outside of my `www` directory. Also, there where 15 files named `notify.php.1`, `notify.php.2`, `notify.php.3` etc. They all appear to be empty.

What are they? Are they safe to remove?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove these files. These files are created every time the cron job runs, but you can set to auto-delete the file after the cron job runs.

**If you are using `wget`:**

**METHOD 1**

To avoid creating such files, you should add `--delete-after` after `wget` when creating a cron job.

Example

```
0 * * * * wget --delete-after -q http://www.example.com/my-cron.php
```

**METHOD 2**

Example:

```
0 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://your.server/script.php
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll test your solution out, and if it works as expected, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `-O-` to output to `standard output` instead file

```
0 * * * * wget -O- http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

or, use `curl` its default behaviour is to output to `standard output`

```
0 * * * * curl http://www.example.com/cron.php
```